Out of memory exception when loading image from stream
So, I'm making a WinForms application and I need to convert an image to a Base64 string and add it to an xlsx data table. I then read this data and add it to the DataGridView. But on top of that I am also taking the Base64 string and converting it back to a picture and inserting it into a pictureBox(I have a gridBox). And the problem is that in the string
gridBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
exception out of memory occurs. Base64 string is correct, I copied it and ran it through online converter. Maybe the size is too big, though not that big, maybe there are some other subtleties.... Please help me to understand. Thanks in advance!
Here are parts of the code:
Encoding:
private void InsertToExcel(PictureBox gridBox, string excelFilePath, string sheetName)
{
    Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    excelApp.Visible = false;

    Excel.Workbook workbook;
    Excel.Worksheet worksheet;

    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
    worksheet = null;

    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in workbook.Sheets)
    {
        if (sheet.Name == sheetName)
        {
            worksheet = sheet;
        }
    }

    Image image = gridBox.BackgroundImage; // here it is

    byte[] imageBytes;

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(memoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        imageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

    worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = Update(_path);
    worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = _minValue;
    worksheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = imageBase64;

    workbook.Close(true);
    excelApp.Quit();

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(worksheet);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
}

Decoding:
private void Search_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenExcelFile(filename);
}

private void OpenExcelFile(string path)
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);


    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
    DataSet db = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
    {
        ConfigureDataTable = (x) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
        {
            UseHeaderRow = false
        }
    });

    tableCollection = db.Tables;

    comboBox.Items.Clear();

    foreach (DataTable table in tableCollection)
    {
        comboBox.Items.Add(table.TableName);
    }

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;

    stream.Close();
}

private void comboBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable table = tableCollection[Convert.ToString(comboBox.SelectedItem)];
    gridView.DataSource = table;


    byte[] imageData = Convert.FromBase64String((string)table.Rows[0][2]);

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData)) 
    {
        gridBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream); // Here is the problem
    }

}


Example of an Image in Base64:
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

I tried to just optimize other parts of my App, but here I tried practically nothing, just checked that Encoding works correctly.

OOM is often just a stupid way of saying that an image doesn't work.

But, like, if Base64 string decodes in online-converter correctly, it means that probably the issue is not in that string. That's my point

Or it's not working like that?

Does the exception occur immediately, or after a few images have been loaded into the gridbox? You need to dispose of GDI+ objects after you're done with them (or you'll leak memory), so perhaps you just need to add a "dispose previous image" step before assigning the background image, ie. gridBox.BackgroundImage?.Dispose(); 

i think Image.FromStream(memoryStream) will generate an image and should be disposed.

You do have t Marshal.ReleaseComObject all references you create. It's possible that the sheet and Cells[..., ...] need to be released too.

I need to convert an image to a Base64 string and add it to an xlsx data table - sounds horrific; you have my sympathies. By the way, have you considered a library that makes the Excel file directly, i.e. not needing excel to be installed?

Did you solve your problem @Зязиковартеее? I don't want to leave my answer up if it's not helpful!

You need to dispose of GDI+ objects after you're done with them (or you'll leak memory), so you need to add a "dispose previous image" step before assigning the background image, e.g.:
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData)) 
{
    if (gridBox.BackgroundImage != null)
    {
        var previousImage = gridBox.BackgroundImage;
        gridBox.BackgroundImage = null;
        previousImage.Dispose(); 
    }

    gridBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
}

I suspect there's an additional problem here, as you're disposing of the MemoryStream. I think this will break your image, as it depends on that stream. I would suggest removing the using, as a MemoryStream doesn't actually need to be disposed anyway (it doesn't hold any unmanaged resources). From the documentation:

This type implements the IDisposable interface, but does not actually have any resources to dispose. This means that disposing it by directly calling Dispose() or by using a language construct such as using (in C#) or Using (in Visual Basic) is not necessary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream

var previousImage = gridBox.BackgroundImage;         gridBox.BackgroundImage = null;         previousImage?.Dispose(); might be slightly more concise by avoiding the need for the if.

Since the image is coming from a PictureBox it's unlikely that this code should dispose it. It's up to the UI to dispose of this image.

Hi @Enigmativity, I was assuming (!) that the picture box is being reused to display different images, each of which (apart from any initial image, if there is one) would have been created from the code above (via Image.FromStream). I would not expect the picture box to dispose of those images just because a new image was loaded into the picture box. Surely it's the code's responsibility to dispose of them...

@SimonMᶜKenzie - The code doesn't seem to be setting the image. It just doesn't make sense to dispose of it in this case.

@Enigmativity, maybe we're not understanding each other, but in the question, comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged explicitly sets the image: gridBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);

@SimonMᶜKenzie - Ah, yes, sorry. I was focusing on the code in the code blocks, not the question. You're 100% right.
